# font-awesome icon doesn't show up in [ngClass] in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, ng-class

I'm facing a strange error in my Angular 4 HTML Template, I'm trying to toggle the class of `<i>` tag, but only one class shows up, but not the other. Here is my code;

```
<i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-eye': visible, 'fa fa-eye-slash': !visible}" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "toggle(pass)"></i>
```

TS:

```
visible = false;
toggle(event){
    this.visible = !this.visible;
}
```

When i check my app, the first icon shows up i.e. the default on `fa fa-eye-slash` but when i click on it it shows only box.

[image: HTML:]
[image]

**Edit:**

Tried with different icons from FA, but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the html to:

```
<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-eye': visible, 'fa-eye-slash': !visible}" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "toggle(pass)"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you @peinearydevelopment, that works like charm!